# Centripetal acceleration

Tags: homework-and-exercises, vectors, rotational-kinematics

I know if a particle is accelerating around the earth it has $$a= \omega*v$$ My question is how do I express this in terms of the unit vector. Would it go something like this.

$$|a| = |\omega*v| $$

$$|a| = |\omega||v||\sin 90$$

$$a =- \omega*r*e_r $$

It was a question in a exam paper that came up a few years ago. And I am just not sure how express the acceleration of a satellite with a unit vector.

Comment: Take a look here :http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/250837/. If you don't understand then we'll come back.

Comment: Hi Frobenius, thank you for the link howvever I understand the $\omega$ is perpendicular to the plane and the v is in the direction of motion and it is constantly changing. And then using the right and rule that the direction of accelartion is pointed towards the center. I just am having difficulty with expressing it

Comment: I think that your difficulty is about the outer product of two  3-vectors :$\mathbf{\omega} \times \mathbf{r}$. Try to look at this and understand as a vector not as  a number equal to the areaof a parallelogram. On the other hand, what is the necessity of the unit vector ?

Comment: Ya I don't really understand how you went from $\omega * \omega * r= \omega ^2 R *u_n$

Comment: I just don't understand $u_n$ is the unit vector pointed towards the object that it is rotating about.

Comment: Ok. Let explain :
$$
\|\boldsymbol{\omega} \boldsymbol{\times} \mathbf{r} \|=\omega \cdot R,    \quad   \omega \equiv \| \boldsymbol{\omega} \| 
\tag{01}
$$
$R$ is  the magnitude of the component of $\mathbf{r}$ normal to $\boldsymbol{\omega}$, it's the radius of revolution around the  $\boldsymbol{\omega}$-axis, see the second Figure in the link. $R$ is not the  magnitude of $\mathbf{r}$.

Comment: $$
\| \boldsymbol{\omega} \boldsymbol{\times}\left(\boldsymbol{\omega} \boldsymbol{\times} \mathbf{r} \right) \|=\| \boldsymbol{\omega} \| \cdot \| \boldsymbol{\omega} \boldsymbol{\times} \mathbf{r} \| \cdot \sin \underbrace{<\boldsymbol{\omega} ,\left(\boldsymbol{\omega} \boldsymbol{\times} \mathbf{r} \right)}_{\pi/2}>=\omega^{2} \; R
\tag{02}
$$